# How to create a quick, one-off admin page without compiling

Tags: admin-pages

I need to make a quick Sitecore admin script to inspect a series of items.  I need to do this without compiling my solution.
I made a sample ASPX page under `/sitecore/admin/` using:

```xml
<script runat="server" language="text/c#">
```

but when I try to view it I get Sitecore telling me `ItemNotFound`.

Is this type of 'pure script' page supported under Sitecore?  Is there a piece of functionality I am missing?

Comment: Adding this as a comment as it's not an answer to your specific question, but if you haven't already I would strongly recommend you investigate the Sitecore Powershell Extensions module. Once installed on your Sitecore instance, this will allow you to run scripts to inspect / interact with items without requiring compilation. It's perfect for those sort of admin tasks but does lots more too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wasnt extending the adminpage base class.  My script tag should have read like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" Inherits="Sitecore.sitecore.admin.AdminPage" %>
```

There a good writeup and example page in [this post on BrainJocks](http://jockstothecore.com/creating-a-quick-admin-script-to-run-within-sitecore/).

Answer (score 4):

If Sitecore is telling you `ItemNotFound`, then it's trying to resolve your request to a content item. Being your admin page is a physical file, the issue is most likely that you've not included the file extension in the request.

For example, to access the `ShowConfig` admin page I must include the `aspx` extension of the file when I request it:

```
http://mysite/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx
```

If I leave the `aspx` off, I'll get an `ItemNotFound` error.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, sample code snippet for that:

```c#
<%@ Page Language="c#" EnableEventValidation="false" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        repValues.DataBind();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Names
    {
        get
        {
            return new[] { "1", "2" };
        }
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Admin page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Repeater ID="repValues" runat="server" DataSource="<%# Names %>">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# (Container.DataItem as string) %>
                    <br />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
I am glad that you solved your issue ;)